# Debugging Redux / React with Webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux

I have been working recently to learn Redux, and now working some with React as well, since the two seem to go well together. So, when working with the todos react example, I was wanting to dig into the code a little bit and check things out. I realized I am unable to debug much of anything behind the scenes. When I set breakpoints, sometimes the breakpoints trigger, most of the time they don't.

What I want is to be able to debug the ES6 / babel code in that `todos` example project. Now, I am new to ES6 and to Webpack. So I was wondering: How can I accomplish that? I have the react debugger and the redux-dev-tools installed. That all works just fine. But how do I debug my ES6 code? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup webpack to deliver source-maps so that you can examine the code in the dev tools of your browser.

You can add enable them with adding a line to your webpack.config.js, the available options and their meaning can be found [here](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devtool).

e.g.:

```
const config = {
  // [your configuration]
  devtool: '#inline-source-map',
}
```